# Problem using aggregation in mongodb retrieving data from two collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am strugling with a query that i don't know how to perform... I have two collections,

**Tarifas Collection**

```
tarifaConfig = new Schema({
    producto: { type: String },
    titulo: { type: String },
    bloqueo: { type: Boolean },
    margen: { type: Number },
    precioVenta: { type: Number },
    precioVentaIva: { type: Number },
})

const tarifaSchema = new Schema({
    codigo: { type: String },
    titulo: { type: String },
    margen: { type: Number },
    estado: { type: Boolean },
    bloqueo: { type: Boolean },
    configs: [tarifaConfig]
})
```

**Producto Collection**

```
const productosSchema = new Schema({
    ref: { type: String },
    nombre: { type: String },
    precioCompra: { type: Number },
    precioCompraIva: { type: Number },
    precioVenta: { type: Number },
    precioVentaIva: { type: Number },
    iva: { type: Number },
})
```

Now i am using an Aggregation method to retrieve both collection in a response

```
 productosModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "tarifas",
                as: "tarifas",
                pipeline: []
            }
        }
    ]).then((producto) => {
        res.json(producto);
    })
```

This is working and gives me both collections in the response... but..
In tarifa's collection i have a propertie called 'configs' that is an array with lot of sub collections... this sub collections are a config of each product that i have,
So what i need to do is, retrieve all tarifas that has a configs for the product, and if the configs does not contain retrieve the tarifa with a empty array.

**Expected result**

```
{
   ref: 'rbe34',
   nombre: 'bike',
   precioCompra: 10,
   precioCompraIva: 12.1,
   precioVenta: "",
   precioVentaIva: "",
   iva: 21,
   tarifas:[
   { 
    codigo: 'NOR',
    titulo: 'Normal tarifa',
    margen: 33,
    estado: true,
    bloqueo: true,
    configs: [], ///HERE I NEED A EMPTY ARRAY IF THERE IS NOT ANY CONFIG THAT MATCH WITH THE PRODUCT ID,  
   }
   ]
}
```

i tried to add $match in my aggregation pipeline.

```
   productosModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "tarifas",
                as: "tarifas",
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { 'configs.producto': req.params.id } }
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
```

But if there is not any config that match the product it doesn't retrieve the rest of Tarifa's collection

Comment: Can you post please sample data + expected result

Comment: @Valijon damn, sorry if i am not explaining it well

Comment: How do you determine that a specific config matches the product or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to `$filter` the array after you retrieve it.

This pipeline will return only the configs for which the `producto` field from the config matches the `ref` field from the product.

```
    [
        {
            $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "tarifas",
                as: "tarifas",
                pipeline: [
                  {
                    $addFields: {
                         "tarifas.configs":{ $filter:{
                                               input: "$tarifas.configs",
                                                cond: {$eq:["$$this.producto","$ref"]}
                           } }
                       } 
                   }
               ]
            }
        },

    ]
```

Change the fields in the `$eq` array to the ones you need to match.

Comment: i think you are really close... but i am doing $$this.producto, which is the field that i am looking inside the tarifas.config array, and i am changing $ref for the data that i want filter... but is not retreiving me config inside the array... it is retreiving with the tarifas agreggation but tarifas.config is empty... and i am checking the collection and there is a register that match with it :S

Comment: I tried a lot of ways to find the problem, and it seems that in $filter:{ input: "$tarifas.configs", } is not filtering good, because i tried to filter something up level like 
$filter:{ input: "$tarifas", cond:{$eq: [""$$this._id, ID] and it is filtering correctly... so why it input: "$tarifas.configs" is not filtering... maybe because configs is an array?.... dunno

Comment: ok solved it, just adding the $addFields in the pipeline and it is working... thanks man i am learning a lot about the power of aggregation ;:D